# Python for loop parallelization with arbitrarily large *shared* datastructures

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize some python code and am unsure as to the best way to go about doing so. I specifically want to parallelize the top `for` loop in `LS_calculations()` by having each process do a certain chunk of the iterations, similar to a `#pragma omp parallel for` in cpp.

I have these data structures:

u/v/wold are large 2-d lists (think a few hundred MB each)

u/v/wcopy are of the size numThreads * u/v/wold, e.g. size of ucopy = numThreads * uold (think a few GB each)

tensor is a massive 3-d list written as its own class

```
def LS_calculation(ucopy, vcopy, wcopy, uold, vold, wold, tensor, a):
    
    # iterate through tensor
    for i in range(tensor.dims[0]):
        top = [ None for i in range(3) ]
        #proc_id = current_process()._identity[0] - 1
        proc_id = 0
        for j in range(tensor.dims[1]):
            for k in range(tensor.dims[2]):
                tensorAt = tensor.at([i, j, k])

                top[0] = vold[a][j] * wold[a][k] * tensorAt
                ucopy[proc_id][a][i] += top[0]

                top[1] = uold[a][i] * wold[a][k] * tensorAt
                vcopy[proc_id][a][j] += top[1]

                top[2] = uold[a][i] * vold[a][j] * tensorAt
                wcopy[proc_id][a][k] += top[2]
    return


for a in range(A):
    LS_calculation(ucopy, vcopy, wcopy, uold, vold, wold, tensor, approximation)
```

Lots of Googling pointed me to multiprocessing.map, multiprocessing.imap, or multiprocessing.starmap.

I think that map/imap is out because they only takes 1 iterable and I have to pass in multiple data structures. It looks as though these map/imap can parallelize if the data is split manually and the size of the structures is known.

I've looked at starmap, as well, but similarly to map/imap, I don't see how  starmap can be used without splitting the data structures.

How do I parallelize the `for i in range(tensor.dims[0])` loop so that each process does some number of iterations of the for loop? Am I thinking about this the wrong way, or is this a difficult problem for Python?

EDIT: Clarified my question and removed cpp code as that seemed to distract from what I'm asking

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: I felt like I was reading an article rather than a question.

Comment: You need to clear up a lot of misconceptions like python's "shared pointer" model and that both imap and map are identical. Anyway, just rewrite the above code to run in 1 thread in python, and parallelizing it will be simple ... But nost of the time code is ported from python to c++ not the other way around ... So you could just wrap your code as python extension.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For what it's worth `imap` cannot take a "tuple of iterables"; it takes a single iterable like `map` whose elements *might* be tuples of whatever types you want. And then you say, "but I have more data than that." What does that mean?